# Why can't we chain javascript createElement() and setAttribute()?

Tags: javascript

We can do this,

```
var someDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
someDiv1.setAttribute('class', 'someClass');
```

Because of the above code, we naturally tempt to think that below code may work also.

```
var someDiv2 = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'someClass');
```

Actually it works. But the problem is when we try to do this

```
        document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(someDiv2);
```

**It gives an error!!!**

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
> parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
> at HTMLImageElement.

Even though the second code block is working it is useless. Because we can't show the created "div" element.

What is the reason?

Comment: Is that a typo in your question `.appendChild(soemDiv2)` or in the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi ! Please make a snippet firing the "error" you didn't provide us :)

Comment: @phuzi it's a typo. Thank you for informing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code block of the question gives a "div" element as the output. If you run below code

```
console.log(someDiv1);
```

you can see the output of **someDiv1** variable like this.

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

If you execute the above code before the **second line** of the first code block of the question you will get

```
<div></div>
```

as the output. Because it hasn't added the class attribute to the created "div" element yet. And by executing the second line it will add the class attribute to that "div" element.

But if you do the same thing to the **someDiv2** variable the output will be ****undefined****. That means the second code block of the question has no output. That's why it gives an error when trying to use **appendChild()**. But Why **????**

The reason is the latter part of the second code block.

```
.setAttribute('class', 'someClass');
```

It sets the class attribute to the created "div" element. But doesn't output anything instead it just does something. Even though the former part of the second code block gives an output, the latter part is the one which gives the final output for being assigned to the variable. Since it doesn't give any output there is no value for **someDiv2** variable.

But actually that second code block is executed without any problem. The only problem is the variable has no value. So it wouldn't give any errors until we are going to use the **someDiv2** variable in somewhere. But the problem is to show the created "div" element we definitely have to use the **someDiv2** variable.

So ***concatenating*** **"setAttribute()"** and **"createElement()"** is useless.

So what if do this instead of assigning to a variable.

```
document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'someClass');
```

NO. This would not work as well. You can understand it, since the concatenation of **setAttribute()** and **createElement()** doesn't give exact output, **appendChild()** function has no input too. So it gives errors.

This is same for other functions like **setAttribute()** and **createElement()**. Like if you try to concatenate,

- **getElementsByClassName()** and **setAttribute()**
- **createElement()** and **classList.add()**
- **createElement()** and **className**
- **getElementById()** and **classList.add()**
- **getElementsByClassName()** and **className()**

those will definitely be executed without any problem but no exact output. Actually those are some examples. There are many combinations like that.

**Yes. we usually use that kind of concatenations exactly.** But we have to bear in mind that it these kind of concatenations doesn't give any output. Specially **if we use "createElement()" it will matter a lot.** Because we have to show the output in somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The term you're looking for is [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

> Each method returns an object, allowing the calls to be chained together in a single statement without requiring variables to store the intermediate results.

Which is NOT the case here.

For this to effectively work, each of the function should return an instance of the created object, which is not the case. `.createElement()` will return an HTMLDivElement, then you call `.setAttribute` on the object return by createElement but `.setAttribute` doesn't return anything. What is assigned to `someDiv2` is what is returned by `.setAttribute`, so nothing. If it would have returned the HTMLDivElement, you could have done a one-liner.